# Fixed header whilst scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll, fixed, css-position

I am using a jquery scripts to cause my header to remain fixed to the top whilst scrolling. But at the moment, it's animated and that's quite a distraction. Is there a way I can modify the script so that it doesn't animate?

JQuery;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {

        var $scrollingDiv = $("#header");

        $(window).scroll(function(){            
            $scrollingDiv.stop().animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 0) + "px"}, "fixed" );          
        });
    });


</script>
```

Html;

```
<div id="header">Content</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't the the position to fixed per css?

Comment: worried about IE compatibility!!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the link below as a simple solution to your problem.

> http://www.cssplay.co.uk/layouts/basics2.html

EDIT:
Also the solution from the above link should be cross-browser compatible

Answer (score 0):

Add to the style of the header `position:fixed;`.

Comment: I tried this but it's no more fixed to the top of the screen when you scroll. It's fixed to the position of the scroll bar instead. NB. IE6 doesn't support fixed positions so don't think this will work on there