# jquery header which will stay static while page is scrolled down

Tags: jquery

I have looking for an example to create a header which will stay static while page is scrolled down. Exactly like [this example](http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/).

I looked at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684259/fixed-header-whilst-scrolling), [this one](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/fixed-header-with-scroll-to-problem) and some more but didn't find properly working example.

Thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 

<head>
    <style>
    #header { height: 100px; background:#EEEEEE; }
    #footer { height: 100px; background:#EEEEEE; }
    #content { height: 1000px; background:#CCCCCC; }
    </style>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="container">
      <div id="header">Header</div>
      <div id="content">Content</div>
      <div id="footer">Footer</div>
    </div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS `position:fixed` is what you are looking for:

```
 #header { height: 100px; background:#EEEEEE;top:0;left:0;position:fixed }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use jQuery for this. This can easily be achieved with the [css `position` property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).